# How can i give padding to TextInputLayout Edittext

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

[image]

Here in this picture you can see that second edittext not well looking like first one before using TextInputLayout it was not like that. Both Edittexts are given 15dp padding and every parameters are equal.

How can I make second Edittext look like first one.

Comment: Give padding to EditText instead..

Comment: that did not helped it gives padding to first one but not second.

Comment: post your xml ..